# Split String into Array keeping delimiter/separator in Swift

Tags: swift, string

Looking for an (elegant) solution for splitting a string and keeping the separator as item(s) in the array

example 1:

```
"hello world"

["hello", " ", "world"]
```

example 2:

```
" hello world"

[" ", "hello", " ", "world"]
```

thx.

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/q/32361412 ?

Comment: @MartinR thx for the link. I searched for solutions, and havent found this one. the solution(s) of that question are inspiring, yet don't work with separators longer than one char. example 2 seems to not work as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose you are splitting the string by a separator called `separator`, you can do the following:

```
let result = yourString.components(separatedBy:  separator) // first split
                        .flatMap { [$0, separator] } // add the separator after each split
                        .dropLast() // remove the last separator added
                        .filter { $0 != "" } // remove empty strings
```

For example:

```
let result = " Hello World ".components(separatedBy:  " ").flatMap { [$0, " "] }.dropLast().filter { $0 != "" }
print(result) // [" ", "Hello", " ", "World", " "]
```

Comment: @Sweeper I thought there was a version of `components(separatedBy:)` that had an optional parameter to exclude empty results. Have you seen anything like that?

Comment: [I know you can do that in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) but I don't think that exists in Swift. @Alexander

Answer (score 1):

For people who have a condition for their split, for example: splitting a camelCaseString based on uppercase condition:

```
extension Sequence {
    func splitIncludeDelimiter(whereSeparator shouldDelimit: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [[Element]] {
        try self.reduce([[]]) { group, next in
            var group = group
            if try shouldDelimit(next) {
                group.append([next])
            } else {
                group[group.lastIdx].append(next)
            }
            return group
        }
    }
}
```

For example:

```
"iAmCamelCase".splitIncludeDelimiter(whereSeparator: \.isUppercase)
=>
["i", "Am", "Camel", "Case"]
```

(If you want the imp of isUppercase)

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let uppercaseLetters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
}

extension Unicode.Scalar {
    var isUppercase: Bool {
        CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, the [Swift Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) package contains an algorithm called [Intersperse](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Intersperse.md)

After adding the package and

```
import Algorithms
```

you can write

```
let string = "hello world"
let separator = " "

let result = Array(string
                     .components(separatedBy: separator)
                     .interspersed(with: separator))
print(result)
```

Your second example is barely correct, the result of splitting `" hello world"` by space is

```
["", "hello", "world"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let sample = "a\nb\n\nc\n\n\nd\n\nddddd\n \n  \n  \n\n"

let sep = "\n"

let result = sample.components(separatedBy: sep).flatMap {
    $0 == "" ? [sep] : [$0, sep]
}.dropLast()


debugPrint(result) // ArraySlice(["a", "\n", "b", "\n", "\n", "c", "\n", "\n", "\n", "d", "\n", "\n", "ddddd", "\n", " ", "\n", "  ", "\n", "  ", "\n", "\n"])
```