# Cursor moving up and down

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, cursor, uitextview

I have a UITextView in my app which is updated as the user types. But when I start typing in the UITextView, the cursor starts to flicker and move up and down quickly. How can I fix this bug?

This is how the UITextView is update-

A Cocoa Touch Class file called Highlighter.swift-

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

// text hightlighter

class SyntaxGroup {

var wordCollection : [String]
var type : String
var color : UIColor

init(wordCollection_I : [String], type_I : String, color_I: UIColor) {

    wordCollection = wordCollection_I
    type = type_I
    color = color_I

}
}

class SyntaxDictionairy {

var collections : [SyntaxGroup] = []

}

class SyntaxRange {

var range : NSRange
var color : UIColor

init (color_I : UIColor, range_I : NSRange) {
    color = color_I
    range = range_I
}

}

class HighLighter {

private var ranges : [SyntaxRange] = []
var highlightedString : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
var syntaxDictionairy : SyntaxDictionairy

init (syntaxDictionairy_I : SyntaxDictionairy) {

    syntaxDictionairy = syntaxDictionairy_I

}

func run(string : String?, completion: (finished: Bool) -> Void) {

    ranges = []
    highlightedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var baseString = NSMutableString()

    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) { () -> Void in

        if string != nil && string != "" {

            self.highlightedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string!)

            for i in 0..<self.syntaxDictionairy.collections.count {

                for iB in 0..<self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].wordCollection.count {

                    let currentWordToCheck = self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].wordCollection[iB]
                    baseString = NSMutableString(string: string!)

                    while baseString.containsString(self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].wordCollection[iB]) {

                        let nsRange = (baseString as NSString).rangeOfString(currentWordToCheck)
                        let newSyntaxRange = SyntaxRange(color_I: self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].color, range_I: nsRange)
                        self.ranges.append(newSyntaxRange)

                        var replaceString = ""
                        for _ in 0..<nsRange.length {
                            replaceString += "§" // secret unallowed character
                        }
                        baseString.replaceCharactersInRange(nsRange, withString: replaceString)
                    }
                }
            }
            for i in 0..<self.ranges.count {

                self.highlightedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: self.ranges[i].color, range: self.ranges[i].range)

            }
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in

            completion(finished: true)
        }

    }
}

}
```

This is the code in the ViewController.swift file-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

var syntaxHighLighter : HighLighter!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setUpHighLighter()
    myTextView.delegate = self

}

func setUpHighLighter() {

    // build a dict of words to highlight
    let redColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let blueColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0)
    let greenColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.5, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let redGroup = SyntaxGroup(wordCollection_I: ["red","bordeaux"], type_I: "Color", color_I: redColor)
    let blueGroup = SyntaxGroup(wordCollection_I: ["coralblue","blue","skyblue","azur"], type_I: "Color", color_I: blueColor)
    let greenGroup = SyntaxGroup(wordCollection_I: ["green"], type_I: "Color", color_I: greenColor)

    let dictionairy : SyntaxDictionairy = SyntaxDictionairy()
    dictionairy.collections.append(blueGroup)
    dictionairy.collections.append(greenGroup)
    dictionairy.collections.append(redGroup)

    syntaxHighLighter = HighLighter(syntaxDictionairy_I: dictionairy)

}

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
    let currentRange = myTextView.selectedRange
    syntaxHighLighter.run(myTextView.text) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.myTextView.attributedText = self.syntaxHighLighter.highlightedString
        self.myTextView.selectedRange = currentRange
    }

}

   }
```

Comment: are you changing the frame of UITextView view programatically ?

Comment: @RahulMishra I am not changing the frame, I am changing the text colour of text typed in. Yes, this is done programmatically.

Comment: NSRange problem. Can't say more, because again a question without code or any form of illustration.

Comment: @RMenke It is the code you typed for the Syntax Colouring app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356321/making-a-text-view-respond-to-text-typed-by-the-user?noredirect=1#comment52631065_32356321

Comment: please read [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question

Comment: @RMenke I updated the question

Comment: It might be possible that on a slower device the highlighter isn't finished before the next change happens. Adding a bool to prevent that will help. `if highlighterIsRunning == true { return }

Comment: @RMenke I didn't get it. Where should I add this? I tried setting it to true at the end of setUpHighlighter and then typing this in the textViewDidChange function - highlighterIsRunning == false {
        let currentRange = textView.selectedRange
        
        syntaxHighLighter.run(textView.text) { (finished) -> Void in
            self.textView.attributedText = self.syntaxHighLighter.highlightedString
            self.textView.selectedRange = currentRange
}

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are running the latest OS and Xcode.

Try this to figure out when it is jumping:
You could again use a `bool` to check if the selection change is because of the reset after highlighting or not. If it is not you can use a breakpoint to see what is going on.

```
func textViewDidChangeSelection(textView: UITextView) {

   print("selection changed: \(myTextView.selectedTextRange!)")

}
```

This could help: a check too see if the length of the textview is still equal to the length of the highlighted string.

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    let currentRange = myTextView.selectedRange

    syntaxHighLighter.run(myTextView.text) { (finished) -> Void in

        // if the highlighter was slower than typing, ABORT
        guard let textInUITextView = self.myTextfield.attributedText where textInUITextView.length == self.syntaxHighLighter.highlightedString.length else {
            return
        }

        self.myTextView.attributedText = self.syntaxHighLighter.highlightedString
        self.myTextView.selectedRange = currentRange
    }

}
```

This could help: it will prevent the highlighter from running more than once.

```
class HighLighter {

    private var ranges : [SyntaxRange] = []
    var highlightedString : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var syntaxDictionairy : SyntaxDictionairy

    private var running : Bool = false

    init (syntaxDictionairy_I : SyntaxDictionairy) {

        syntaxDictionairy = syntaxDictionairy_I

    }

    func run(string : String?, completion: (finished: Bool) -> Void) {

        if running == true {
            print("double action")
            return
        }

        running = true

        ranges = []
        highlightedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        var baseString = NSMutableString()

        let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) { () -> Void in

            if string != nil && string != "" {

                self.highlightedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string!)

                for i in 0..<self.syntaxDictionairy.collections.count {

                    for iB in 0..<self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].wordCollection.count {

                        let currentWordToCheck = self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].wordCollection[iB]
                        baseString = NSMutableString(string: string!)

                        while baseString.containsString(self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].wordCollection[iB]) {

                            let nsRange = (baseString as NSString).rangeOfString(currentWordToCheck)
                            let newSyntaxRange = SyntaxRange(color_I: self.syntaxDictionairy.collections[i].color, range_I: nsRange)
                            self.ranges.append(newSyntaxRange)

                            var replaceString = ""
                            for _ in 0..<nsRange.length {
                                replaceString += "§" // secret unallowed character
                            }
                            baseString.replaceCharactersInRange(nsRange, withString: replaceString)
                        }
                    }
                }
                for i in 0..<self.ranges.count {

                    self.highlightedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: self.ranges[i].color, range: self.ranges[i].range)

                }
            }

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
                self.running = false
                completion(finished: true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. The cursor is still vibrating and moving up and down.

Comment: You might figure out more by getting a `print()` from the `myTextView.selectedRange` at various moments. If there are jumps in values that are not caused by the input you will at least now which bit is causing all this.

Comment: This is what is causing the cursor to act in this weird fashion- `self.myTextView.attributedText = self.syntaxHighLighter.highlightedString`
But I don't think I can eliminate this right?

Comment: I'm testing on the iPhone 6

Comment: I replicated your github project since I couldn't run the downloaded project for some reason, and the cursor still vibrated. I can mail the replicated project to you if you want. You can check what's wrong.

Comment: Are you ok with me mailing the project to you?

Comment: Also, there is no UITextField in the app, and the updated answer includes a UITextField.

Comment: Of course. I know that. I just said that for the benefit of others who visit this question. However, what confuses me is that both of our projects have the exact same code, but yours works just fine, and mine does not.

Comment: It's very weird. I am thinking swift 1.2 vs swift 2.0 or iOS 8 vs iOS 9?

Comment: Hey, guess what? You were right! It was the iOS 8-iOS 9 barrier because it works on Xcode 7 beta 5! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89475/discussion-between-r-menke-and-krish-wadhwana).